# python Numpy transpose and calculate

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am relatively new to python and numpy. I am currently trying to replicate the following table as shown in the image in python using numpy.

[image]
As in the figure, I have got the columns "group, sub_group,value" that are populated. I want to transpose column "sub_group" and do a simple calculation i.e. value minus shift(value) and display the figure in the lower diagonal of the matrix for each group. If sub_group is "0", then assign the whole column as 0. The **transposed sub_group** can be named anything (preferably index numbers) if it makes it easier. I am ok with a pandas solution as well. I just think pandas may be slow?

Below is code in array form:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([(1,-1,10),(1,0,10),(1,-2,15),(1,-3,1),(1,-4,1),(1,0,12),(1,-5,16)], dtype=[('group',float),('sub_group',float),('value',float)])
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Regards,
S

Comment: What do you mean `value-shift(value)`I don't get it

Comment: Hello MMF, i mean to say first value - second value, then first value - third value, then first value - fourth value, and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a=np.array([(1,-1,10),(1,0,10),(1,-2,15),(1,-3,1),(1,-4,1),(1,0,12),(1,-5,16)], dtype=[('group',float),('sub_group',float),('value',float)])
df = pd.DataFrame(a)

for i in df.index:
    col_name = str(int(df['sub_group'][i]))
    df[col_name] = None

    if df['sub_group'][i] == 0:
        df[col_name] = 0
    else:
        val = df['value'][i]
        for j in range(i, df.index[-1]+1):
            df[col_name][j] = val - df['value'][j]
```

For the upper triangle of the matrix, I have put `None`values. You can replace it by whatever you want.

Comment: The array `a` you gave in your code is not the same as the one on your excel sheet.

Comment: lol. I am so stupid when it comes to presenting information on stack overflow. Thank you MMF, u r a Pi-genius.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code does the calculation for the example of the subgroup, I am not  sure if this is what you actually want, in that case post a comment here and I will edit

```
import numpy as np
array_1=np.array([(1,-1,10),(1,0,10),(1,-2,15),(1,-3,1),(1,-4,1);(1,0,12),(1,-5,16)])
#transpose the matrix
transposed_group = array_1.transpose()
#loop over the first row
for i in range(0,len(transposed_group[1,:])):
#value[i] - first value of the row
    transposed_group[0,i] = transposed_group[0,i] - transposed_group[0,0]
print  transposed_group
```

In case you want to display that in the diagonal of the matrix, you can loop through the rows and columns, as for example:

```
import numpy as np
#create an array of 0
array = np.zeros(shape=(3,3))
#fill the array with 1 in the diagonals
print array
#loop over rows
for i in range(0,len(array[:,1])):
    #loop over columns
    for j in range(0,len(array[1,:])):
        array[i,j] = 1

print array
```

Comment: Hello Praderas, Thank you for your solution. It does not work as intended, but nevertheless a solution to keep in mind. thank you once again